# java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: java, database, ms-access, datasource, jdbc-odbc

I have a java application that uses access database. My PC has 64-bit Operating System, 64-bit Microsoft Office, and 64-bit JDK. I even installed the Access Database Engine x64. Basically everything on it is 64-bit.

In control panel, my target is `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe` and I specified that start in: `%windir%\SysWOW64`. The problem now this error message that I keep on getting.

> java.sql.SQLException:[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Does any one know what is causing this error?

Comment: What is causing this error? Is there a specific line of code? Does it happen at runtime or compile?

Comment: what driver are you using ? can you name it?

Comment: @Scott it is a runtime error.The error has nothing to do with a code.Bacause when im using my other lap top which is 32bits everything works fine.@Mukul Goel when i change the target to C:\windows\System32\odbcad32.exe the name of the driver is Microsoft Access driver (*.mdb, *accdb)

Comment: Was the Access database *created* with the 32 bit Access version, *then* you upgraded Access to 64 bit?

Answer (score 2):

OK, in that case you will need 64-bit drivers if your Java app is running 64-bit. I believe there is a 64-bit download at the below link:

[Microsoft Access Database Engine 2010 Redistributable](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255)